# Binding listeners inside of a for loop : variable scope miscomprehension

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I've a variable scope problem and I don't understand why this occurs and how to get rid of it :

```
    var items = ['foo', 'bar'];
    for (var index in items) {
        var item = items[index];
        var selector = '.'+item+'-class';
        $(selector).bind('click', function() {
            console.log("class: "+$(this).attr('class'));
            console.log("selector: "+selector);
            console.log("item: "+item);
        });
    }
```

Considers that this code execute itself over the following HTML :

```
<div class="foo-class">Foo</div>
<div class="bar-class">Bar</div>
```

Clicking on "Foo" echoes the right class (i.e. "foo-class") in the first line but the selector and the item name following are related to bar. I think that the problem is that the second iteration of the loop reset the variables used in the first one.

I thought that the declaration inside of the loop should clearly declare their scope at this level. Am I wrong ? Why ? How can I fix it ?

I'm not seeking a workaround, I want something clean and a better comprehension of javascript variable scope mecanism.

Here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reVRn/).

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your fiddle example updated.

```
var items = ['foo', 'bar'];
for (var index in items) {
    (function() {
        var item = items[index]; 
        var selector = '.' + item + '-class';
        $(selector).bind('click', function() {
            console.log("class: " + $(this).attr('class'));
            console.log("selector: " + selector);
            console.log("item: " + item);
        });
    })();
}​
```

Creating an anonymous function will define a new scope for each of your defined variables

TIP: Try to create a separate function to do the bind, just to keep your code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

It's always the same with these for-loops (google it). JavaScript does not have block scope but function scope, so when an item is clicked the *one* variable `selector` has the value it had after the last loop run (same for the variable `item`).

To solve the problem, you need another closure in you loop which stores the variables in its own scope. That means you need to execute a function for each loop run.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I didn't know this function level variable scope +1

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not strictly about variable scope. The anonymous function runs at the time the click event is triggered, *not* when you are defining it in the loop. Consider the following which is functionally identical to your example:

```
var items = ['foo', 'bar'];

for (var index in items) {
    var item = items[index];
    var selector = '.'+item+'-class';
    $(selector).bind( 'click', test );
}
​
function test() {
    console.log("selector: "+selector);
}
```

This (hopefully) demonstrates what's happening: the global variable `selector` in the function is, at the time the function is being called, the same in both cases ("bar").

Comment: Thanks but I doubt that selector will be set when test will called.

Comment: Why not? It's a global variable.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this for was a function ... don't know why. You're correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = ['foo', 'bar'];
for (var index in items) {
    (function(i){  
    var item = items[i];
    var selector = '.'+item+'-class';
    $(selector).bind('click', function() {
            console.log("class: "+$(this).attr('class'));
            console.log("selector: "+selector);
            console.log("item: "+item);
        });
    })(index);
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/tKFD2/)

Answer (score 0):

Vars "selector" and "item" are references to a location where you store values, and the values of those two at the moment you click one of the htl elements is the one frome the last loop.