# Merging three click functions into one jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an array full of `MapIcon` that each contain a name and an image.

The array is called `mapIcon`.

We have these three functions which work when defining each instance separately, but when I try to make it into one function that determines which image the user clicks on, I come to a problem.

```
mapIcon[0].click(function(){
    var selectedMap = ($('<img src="img/' + maps[0].image + '">'));
    gameplayScreen.append(selectedMap);
    mapSelectScreen.fadeOut(500, function() {
        gameplayScreen.fadeIn(500);
        gameplayScreen.show();
    });
});

mapIcon[1].click(function(){
    var selectedMap = ($('<img src="img/' + maps[1].image + '">'));
    gameplayScreen.append(selectedMap);
    mapSelectScreen.fadeOut(500, function() {
        gameplayScreen.fadeIn(500);
        gameplayScreen.show();
    });
});

mapIcon[2].click(function(){
    var selectedMap = ($('<img src="img/' + maps[2].image + '">'));
    gameplayScreen.append(selectedMap);
    mapSelectScreen.fadeOut(500, function() {
        gameplayScreen.fadeIn(500);
        gameplayScreen.show();
    });
});

gameplayScreen.click(function() {
    gameplayScreen.fadeOut(500, function() {
        mapSelectScreen.fadeIn(500);
        mapSelectScreen.show();
        gameplayScreen.empty();
    });
});
```

I want to click on the map, and then have it take me to the `gameplayScreen`, and then click again to take me back like these functions do.

I assume it has something to do with using a for loops and iterating through it for the clicks a'la `mapIcon[i].click(function(){/*foo*/})` but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I guess it doesn't like taking an array element for `.click`. Any ideas? This is the current attempt at an all in one function.

```
for (i=0; i< mapIcon.length; i++){
    mapIcon[i].click(function(){
    var selectedMap = ($('<img src="img/' + mapIcon[i].image + '">'));
            gameplayScreen.append(selectedMap);
            mapSelectScreen.fadeOut(500, function() {
                gameplayScreen.fadeIn(500);
                gameplayScreen.show();
                console.log(mapIcon[i].name);
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131647/binding-listeners-inside-of-a-for-loop-variable-scope-miscomprehension

Comment: How do you populate the array?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (i=0; i< mapIcon.length; i++){
    (function(){
      var item = mapIcon[i];
      item.click(function(){
            var selectedMap = ($('<img src="img/' + item.image + '">'));
            gameplayScreen.append(selectedMap);
            mapSelectScreen.fadeOut(500, function() {
                gameplayScreen.fadeIn(500);
                gameplayScreen.show();
                console.log(item.name);
            });
        });
    })();
}
```

It should clear the [scope issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131647/binding-listeners-inside-of-a-for-loop-variable-scope-miscomprehension)

Comment: I tried both of these options, with the results acting pretty much the same. It is now recognizing that I'm clicking on a map, but is only fading out without fading in the desired map that was clicked on and appended to gameplayScreen. I'll keep messing with it. You guys have helped me get a step closer at least. I swear I tried a temp variable to keep it within scope, and it wouldn't work. If you have any ideas why it might not be fading in the correct screen, let me know.

Comment: Actually, I think I know why it isn't working correctly...sorta. When item gets filled with mapIcon[i], it already has a value, and that may be a different result than where I click on the screen. If it's filled with castle.png for instance, and I click on the forest map which should load forest.png (instance 2 of mapIcon), how would it know? Is there a way to load in the map that i choose by clicking on it? It's hard to explain what I'm asking, but I need to click on a map, and have it load that map to gameplayScreen, rather than doing mapIcon[0]..[1]..[2]. I don't think it reaches 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your handler separately and then assigning it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var i = 0,
        switchMap = function switchMap(e) {
            var selectedMap = $('<img />').attr({
                'src': 'img/' + this.image,
                'alt': this.name
            });
            gameplayScreen.append(selectedMap);
            mapSelectScreen.fadeOut(500, function () {
                gameplayScreen.fadeIn(500);
                gameplayScreen.show();
            });
        };
    for (i = 0; i < mapIcon.length; i += 1) {
        mapIcon[i].click(switchMap);
    }
    gameplayScreen.click(function () {
        gameplayScreen.fadeOut(500, function () {
            mapSelectScreen.fadeIn(500);
            mapSelectScreen.show();
            gameplayScreen.empty();
        });
    });
});
```